Using SSE in Flask
I'm using Flask to develop a web app. I have a /stream route in my python code, an index.html file, and a stream_page.html that triggers the stream route.
I want to trigger a stream from stream_page.html, calling the /stream route with a POST call. I want to have the streamed text show up in index.html.
The /stream route returns a Response object, and I can see the streaming happen in a new blank page. But I don't want to see it in a new blank page. I don't want to see it in stream_page.html either. I want to see it in index.html. How can I get the Response object to stream in index.html?
Here's roughly what I have so far.
app.py:
@app.route('/stream', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def stream():
    data = request.form['data']
    def gen(data):
        yield ...
    return Response(gen(data), content_type='text/event_stream')

index.html:
 <script>
    if (!!window.EventSource) {
        var source = new EventSource('/stream');

        source.onmessage = function(event) {
            var newElement = document.getElementById(stream_div);
            newElement.innerHTML = event.data;
            document.getElementById("events").appendChild(newElement);
        };

        source.onerror = function(event) {
            console.error("EventSource failed:", event);
        };
    } else {
        console.error("Your browser does not support SSE.");
    }
    </script>

stream_page.html:
<form action="{{ url_for('app.stream') }}" method="post">
...
</form>


The response header should be "Content-Type: text/event-stream" and not "text/event_stream"

My code was correct. The problem was that my generator was returning a string of a incorrect format. The format has to be:
f"data:{s}\n\n"
The data and double line breaks must be there for EventSource to work properly.
